# Looking for a tool to stress test an application via Service Bus messages

Tags: azure, performance-testing, azureservicebus

I have an application that subscribes to an Azure Service Bus topic and processes the incoming messages. I would like to do a performance/stress test by constantly sending a very large batch of messages from different locations to the Service Bus and measure the processing time of my application.

Is there a tool out there to flood Service Bus?

Comment: Tool/service recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Apache JMeter is the right tool to test web services. http://jmeter.apache.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend going for [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), it is free, open source, scalable, GUI-based multiprotocol load testing tool.

Given you have [Azure Libraries For Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java-download-azure-sdk) in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you should be able to use the following Test Elements:

- [JMS Publisher](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Publisher)
- [JMS Subscriber](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Subscriber)
- [JMS Point-to-Point](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Point-to-Point)

to mimic the load on ASB.

See [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) for details.

---

Another free and open source tool which can be used is [Gatling](http://gatling.io/), see [JMS API Example](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2/jms/#example) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the sample ASB team has once provided. Saying that, I'd like to warn about tooling - your benchmarking will be off if you're in the standard tier.
Challenge with standard tier is the noisy neighbor effect, when because of your (or someone else) operation you can get throttled.

With premium tier you can get the consistent and promised throughput.